# Creating project using angular cli throws schematic flow error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to learn Angular and have installed nodejs version 14 and installed angularcli but when I use the command ng new proj it throws error

> Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has
> been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see
> https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
> chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to
> chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies. npm WARN deprecated
> fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using
> insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. npm WARN deprecated
> urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated npm
> WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1:
> https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated npm ERR! Unexpected
> end of JSON input while parsing near '...d701271192d27fd28ddc9'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\bhask\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-15T15_42_15_755Z-debug.log
> × Package install failed, see above. The Schematic workflow failed.
> See above.

my project's package.json contents

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.11",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried to uninstall and install older version of nodejs but the issue still prevails

Comment: Can you attach your `package.json`?

Comment: I would also downgrade node to LTS.

Comment: added contents of the package.json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run

> npm cache clean --force

2. Run

> npm i - @angular/cli@latest

3. Then run your project creation command.